# How can I delete these folders with alphanumeric names in the root of drive C:?

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I cannot remove the folders shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

They seem to be trash related to .NET installations. They are very ugly and annoying.

Is there a safe way to remove these folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These folders are the residue of the .net installation. Although most installers always seek the AppData folder residing in the users/username folder. But sometimes the installers first seek which drive is most empty and they extract them or download (their usual process before installing) files into these type of folders (Alphanumeric folders) and then install the files. But they intend to delete the files after the installation this could be halted as many times the installers need a restart to delete these residues but cannot as they cannot be started after a restart or they need certain privileges to delete these folders which they cannot get while running. So these folders show themselves as trash in that drive. You can delete them normally or then take ownership of them and then delete them. Sometime they cannot be deleted as their exe file is still trying to delete these folder but cannot so you might need to close the process(s) from hte task manager. Also there is no harm in deleting these folders and will not certainly infect your system.