# What are all these strange files?

Tags: windows

In my drive D I see these strange folders:

[image]

I can't delete the file

Comment: They are Windows Updates folders.  Windows Update will find the local drive with the most free space.  they can be deleted without a problem since those updates have already been installed

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/694216/folders-with-alphanumeric-names-in-the-root-of-drive-c http://superuser.com/questions/132176/random-directories-in-c-that-i-cannot-delete

Answer (score 2):

They are usually left over temporary files from a Windows update installation or similar.  Looking at the dates on them, they are probably fine to delete.  You just need to up your permissions / log in as administrator / take ownership of the folders if you really want to get rid of them.

Comment: I am an administrator

Comment: There is a difference between 'an' administrator and 'the' administrator.  Right click on the file, Properties, Security tab, and give yourself full control, etc.  You may need to go to Advanced and take ownership of the folder(s).